# router doesn't work on angular4 with command ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to learn **Angular (version 4.3.3)** by by following the tour of heroes tutorials. I started from a clean **angular cli** project and went from there.

I've implemented the routing system of Tour of Heroes. It works fine when I run it with `ng serve` but, if I build by using `ng build` with option `--output-path` and out put the content to my apache localhost server as well as node http-server and try to run then it works, but the routing system doesn't work when I paste it in the address bar.

I'm using all default configuration of a clean angular cli project.

For example, if I click the dashboard link I can go to the heroes dashboard, but, if I paste or write the that same link in address bar it doesn't work. It gives me **"404 Not Found"** .

I can't find the problem. Am I missing something here?

Please could someone point out what the problem could be?

My full ng build command:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --extract-css=true  --output-path "F:\\www\\angular\\heroes" --bh "http://localhost/angular/heroes/" --deploy-url "http://localhost/angular/heroes/"
```

Comment: try to use `HashLocationStrategy` add this to your providers array in app module

Comment: Do you copy with /dist folder or only the content of /dist?

Comment: Actually, I don't need to copy the content or dist folder as I'm using the `--output-path` option with `ng build` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default angular router use [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history). The URL doesn't really exist on the server only inside the user browser. That why you are getting a 404 status code.

To be able to access the URL directly (without having to click on any link from the front page) you need to configure your server (Apache, Nginx, ...) to redirect any request to index.html.

for Apache use rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

for Nginx use try

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

You can find all of this (and more) in the documentation [Server configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml).

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Apache server, so you've to use an .htaccess file  in the root directory and have to  add a [rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to that .htaccess file. Because, according to [angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml):

> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to
>   return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file
>   that it does not have.

You can check [this link](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/) for details.